# How can I test a constraint violation when performing a delete in a Spring integration test?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-test

I want to test that my controller endpoint returns an appropriate error code when trying to delete a record with referencing child records. In my integration test, I need to set up the state so that the related records exist, then invoke the deletion endpoint, expect the error condition, and then (ideally) roll the entire DB back to the state it was in before the test.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO parent_rec (id) VALUES ("foo");
INSERT INTO child_rec (id, parent_id) VALUES ("bar", "foo");
COMMIT;
DELETE FROM parent_rec WHERE id = "foo"; -- bang!
```

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Transactional
void testDelete() {
  // Set up records
  ParentRecord record = new ParentRecord("foo");
  em.persist(record);
  em.persist(new ChildRecord("bar", record));

  //delete
  mockMvc.perform(delete("/parent/foo")).andExpect(/* some error code */);
}
```

However, I'm running into issues. If I put the `@Transactional` annotation at the method or class level, the records aren't persisted until after the deletion is attempted so the deletion returns a 200 OK rather than a 400 Bad Request or similar.

The current solution is for the tests to be run in order (with a previous test setting up records which a subsequent test tries to operate on). However, this makes the tests pretty brittle and dependent on each other, which I'd like to avoid primarily to make changing the code easier.

Can I accomplish what I want without using an additional layer of tooling? In the past, I'd have used DBUnit to do something like this, but if I can avoid adding the additional dependency I'd prefer to keep it simple.

Comment: Does it work if you call `em.flush()` right after the final `em.persist()`?

Answer (score 0):

In JEE I solved these issues kind of simply by splitting my code into two parts:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class ParentRecordTestFacade {

    public void create() {
        // Create record here
    }

    public void delete() {
        // Delete record here
    }
}
```

and then call both methods in the actual unit test one after another.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid the order of the tests being important - will add this to the question. Currently this is the way the tests are implemented, but it means they are very brittle.

Comment: Why should the order be important? Both methods are separated from the actual test to ensure their transaction is committed and please note that `ParentRecordTestFacade` is not a unit test itself.

Comment: Oh, I see - you created this as a separate helper class which your test class had injected into it? I misread this as having methods in the test class. I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Running only some code in a separate transaction also comes in handy. You can achieve it for example by creating a method fo the block of code to invoke in transaction:

```
protected <T> T getInsideTransaction(Function<EntityManager, T> transactional) {
    EntityManager em = null;
    EntityTransaction trx = null;
    try {
        em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        trx = em.getTransaction();
        trx.begin();
        return transactional.apply(em);
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throw throwable;
    } finally {
        if (trx != null) {
            if (!trx.getRollbackOnly()) {
                trx.commit();
            } else {
                trx.rollback();
            }
        }
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can invoke it like that:

```
void testDelete() {
  // Set up records
  getInsideTransaction(em -> {
    ParentRecord record = new ParentRecord("foo");
    em.persist(record);
    em.persist(new ChildRecord("bar", record));
  }

  //delete
  mockMvc.perform(delete("/parent/foo")).andExpect(/* some error code */);
}
```

You can invoke an arbitrary block of code within separate transaction that way.

Comment: all this feature already implemented [TestTransaction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TestTransaction.html)

Comment: @borino ok, I wasn't aware of that. But if you were using hibernate as java ee provider without spring, you would have to implement it yourself or look for something else. So that's why the downvote?

Comment: within the current question, your solution is redundant. But of course it is working solution.

Answer (score 0):

In spring especially for test such cases in repository layer I using, looks like should works and for you - `org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TestTransaction`. Pay attention on `@Commit` annotation on test method, otherwise your record will not be saved.

```
@Commit
void testDelete() {
  // Set up records
  ParentRecord record = new ParentRecord("foo");
  em.persist(record);
  em.persist(new ChildRecord("bar", record));
  TestTransaction.end()

  TestTransaction.start()
  //delete
  mockMvc.perform(delete("/parent/foo")).andExpect(/* some error code */);
}
```

But of course after commit you should delete manually you record.